# What happens if I disconnect from a remote computer while task scheduler is running a task

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I have a windows PowerShell script that runs some commands including an excel macro. I have created a task in task scheduler that runs this PowerShell script every time I remote into a remote computer. The script takes about a minute to run. I was wondering what happens if I log out while task scheduler is running the PowerShell script. The task scheduler task is set to only run when the user is logged in because I couldn't find a way to run excel non-interactively.

Comment: What's stopping you from logoff early and see if it works ?

Comment: If you log out from a remote computer the user usually stays logged in at the remote computer. So if you open Excel at the remote computer disconnect the remote session and connect again, you still see your Excel open. If that is the case it is very likely that your script will run too. If you really logoff your user then the script will very likely stop. Give it a try.

Comment: Used to remote log in to SGI machines running irix and tasks would continue to run when left.